# My object isn't tracking with the empty in final render but it's fine in my layout and 3-d viewport

Tags: compositing-nodes

My graphic tracks with the empty (the running man) fine in my viewport but is almost completely disjointed in my final render
Could you help me see why [https://i.imgur.com/YH5vSnp.gifv] is fine in my viewport but this [https://i.imgur.com/0pQaZU7.gifv] sucks in my final render?